# VPS hang when one Virtual CPU usage is 100%

Tags: vps, xen

We are using Xen Center to manage all of our cPanel VPS servers. The hardware has two CPUs(Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5410@2.33GHz) and 32GB memory. Each hardware has 4 cPanel VPS and each VPS has 8GB memory and 4 Virtual CPUS. Every one or two months, one of the VPS server will hang because one Virtual CPU usage is 100% and it couldn't release the CPU unless we use force reboot. We have 10 similar hardware, and this cause our server down almost every day. We have tried to avoid the Statistics Processing and Fantastico update during the night, but the problem still happens randomly. I can not find anything in the server log when it hangs. Any clue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an ongoing bug with xenconsoled dying - see [bugtraq #593339 (xenconsoled dies randomly and makes it impossible to create new guests)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=593339) if you think this may apply to you.

Comment: Thanks. We are still using 5.0 build 10918. The bug seems for 5.5.

Comment: Problems with xenconsoled buffers have been ongoing since 2006:

http://bugzilla.xensource.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=477

... when I worked for a VPS hosting company, our system administrators elected to restart xenconsoled periodically (every day) and we were mostly able to eliminate the issue by ensuring domU consoles weren't constantly spewing messages (like 4gb seg fixup).